# How to use System Restore on specific Windows when Dual-Booting?

Tags: windows-11, system-restore, windows-restore

So I’ve just messed up all drivers on my main Windows installation and it only lets me boot into recovery mode but when it gets me there, the **System Restore** option proposes me to restore points from my **other Windows installation** even tho **my first main boot entry** in bcd is my main Windows, what’s happening and how can I get restore points for my **main Windows**?

Answer (score 0):

To perform a System Restore for your other Windows installation, boot into **WinRE recovery environment** or a USB Windows installation, open the command prompt(Shift+F10), find the drive letter to your other Windows, and type the following into the prompt: `rstrui.exe /offline:D:\windows` **(make sure to replace D with your drive letter)**

This will open the System Restore window with restore points from your other Windows installation. Thank me later…